# Extract dataframe columns by value type

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

When loading dataframe form excel file I need to identify all columns between two particular ones that have string values. How can I filter or get index of columns by their data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select by strat and end column and then seelct numbers by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) and `np.number`:

```
df1 = df.loc[:, 'start col':'end col'].select_dtypes(np.number)
```

If need columns without `numbers`:

```
df2 = df.loc[:, 'A':'C'].select_dtypes(exclude=np.number)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `select_dtypes` with the `include` argument which accepts a list of types.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [0,1,2,3],
                  'B' : ['A','B','C','D'],
                  'C' : [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4],
                  'D'  : ['C','F','I','L']})


print(df)

   A  B    C  D
0  0  A  0.1  C
1  1  B  0.2  F
2  2  C  0.3  I
3  3  D  0.4  L


start = 0
end = 5
df.iloc[:,start:end].select_dtypes(include=['float64','Int64'])

   A    C
0  0  0.1
1  1  0.2
2  2  0.3
3  3  0.4
```